# Using OwlApi to extract subclasses from owl file with labels

Tags: java, owl

I am looking at extracting classes and subclasses from an owl file. I am using the OwlApi with some guidance from dlquery tutorial example. It works well except for handling entities with reserved characters. I have been advised to use label annotation instead of extracting entities from IRIs, and specifically use the AnnotationValueShortFormProvider instead of SimpleShortFormProvider. Here is my piece of code to retrieve all subclasses. Let's use 'United States' for example as the entity.

```
private Set<OWLClass> getSubClasses(String cls, boolean direct) {
    if (cls.trim().length() == 0) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    OWLClassExpression classExpression = this.parser.parseClassExpression(cls);
    NodeSet<OWLClass> subClasses = this.reasoner.getSubClasses(classExpression, direct);
    return subClasses.getFlattened();
}
```

My parser is set as such:

```
this.parser = new DLQueryParser(rootOntology, shortFormProvider);
```

where shortFormProvider is an instance of AnnotationValueShortFormProvider

My question is, how do I instantiate classExpression without parsing the String 'United States', since parsing the string will extract the prefix/token ‘United’? Or is there another sample code block we could use to retrieve subclasses from using label annotations instead of an IRIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a label like 'United States', the Java string should look like "'United States'".
Single quotes are used for multi word literal values.

If you have the label value you can also look up directly in the ontology without having to use a Manchester syntax parser. In the same documentation page where you can find the DL query example there are also examples on how to tho this.

```
for(OWLClass owlClass: o.getClassesInSignature()){
// Get the annotations on the class that use the label property
for (OWLAnnotation annotation : owlClass.getAnnotations(o, dataFactoryf.getRDFSLabel())) {
    if (annotation.getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral) {
        OWLLiteral val = (OWLLiteral) annotation.getValue();
        if (val.getLiteral().equals(inputLabel)) {
            // at this point, the owlClass variable is the OWLClass you were looking for
            NodeSet<OWLClass> subClasses = this.reasoner.getSubClasses(owlClass, direct);
            return subClasses.getFlattened();
        }
    }
}
}
```

https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation

Comment: Yes, that code helps me to extract a label, which I am already doing. But how do I now extract all subclasses (or labels from subclasses) for that label, like the function I have above? All the documentation examples point to using IRIs to get subclasses and not labels.

Comment: Once you get to the owlClass variable above, you can use it the same way you use classExpression in your example. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That updated code will try to extract subclasses from the class IRI and not from the label. If you run the code with an owl file with class IRI 'US(America)' for example, it will fail with message: `Exception in thread "main" org.semanticweb.owlapi.expression.ParserException: Encountered untitled-ontology-24 at line 1 column 1. Expected one of:
 Class name
 Object property name
 Data property name
 not
 inverse
 (
 {`. I think my real issue is, how to I extract subclasses with support for reserved IRI characters like parenthesis? I thought the answer was using 'labels' somehow.

Comment: Can you add an example string you're trying to parse? In my example, the class IRI is never used to match the input label, only rdfs:label values are used for matching the class. Note that a class label is not part of the IRI - do you mean the local name or the fragment of the class IRI when you say label?

Comment: That code works and marked as accepted! I was not updating the 'getSuperClasses' method with the code change hence the errors. Many thanks! Behind the scenes, looks like it is using the IRI from the class and not the label or IRI prefix in case it has a reserved character, to get the subclasses/superclasses. That is ok. But out of curiosity, why do most of the examples use the Manchester syntax parser, instead of just using the owl class to get the subclasses like above?

Comment: glad that it works. The reason for the examples to be Manchester syntax centred is historical, we should probably revisit them.